# Where does one live after getting moksha?

Tags: puranas, moksha

Where does one live after getting moksha . Some say - Baikunth , some say Go-loka . What is the truth ?

Comment: They go to  Maha Kailasha or Manidweepa and merges into Lord Shiva (Brahman) thats the only truth. Which is called as Kaivalysm Moksha Prapti. The Highest form of Moksha. Period. ..

Comment: @river , while the above comment is the Shaiva sect's view exclusively, however, in the Vaisnava view, they go to the Param Padam Vaikuntha or Goloka. In the Advaita, there's no loka for Moksha or "merging" - but the removal of avidya, just realization. So, anyone saying that there's only one path/or view on Moksha might be misleading. All sects have a different conceptions about Moksha.!:))